# `textscan` reads the opened file only once

Tags: matlab, text

I have a text file like this:

```
3
bcs
acd
hgf
```

The first number shows the number of rows and columns of the following block of characters. (Here, 3 means a 3x3 block)

I want to read this block of strings. I do this as

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
A  = textscan(fid,'%s',3,'HeaderLines',1);
```

and it returns the correct output:

A =

```
{3x1 cell}
```

But if I again want to read the same lines and store it again, it returns and empty cell array:

```
B  = textscan(fid,'%s',3,'HeaderLines',1);
```

B =

```
{0x1 cell}
```

To make it work correctly, I have to `fclose` the file and `fopen` it again. **I mean, I can only read the file once after opening it.**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: In what case do you need to re-read the file, rather than just doing `B=A;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`frewind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/frewind.html) to go back to the beginning of the file, and then you can use `textscan` again:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
A  = textscan(fid,'%s',3,'HeaderLines',1);
frewind(fid)
B  = textscan(fid,'%s',3,'HeaderLines',1);
```

Comment: So, when I read a file, it goes to the end of the last character that was read?

Comment: Yas, I think it works that way. It's like `fread`: the file pointer is advanced as you read its contents